# Understanding "elle. . . ne se relevait que languissante"

Tags: syntaxe, adjectifs

The question is on *languissante* in this passage from La Porte étroite by André Gide.

> Lucile Bucolin ne prenait que peu de part à notre vie ; elle ne descendait de sa chambre que passé le repas de midi ; elle s’allongeait aussitôt sur un sofa ou dans un hamac, demeurait étendue jusqu’au soir et ne se relevait que **languissante**.

**Question**

In terms of formal grammar (syntax), what is the contribution of the word to the sentence?

I am looking for an answer of this type:

- *glissante* is an adjective modifying *elle*.
- *glissante* is an adverb modifying *relevait*.

**Background**

If the sentence ended with *paresseusement*, it would have given me no trouble.  I would have understood, "Lucile Bucolin rose only languidly."

But *languissant* is an adjective in [this dictionary entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/languissant) and no other part of speech.  Alternatively it is a present participle.  (Maybe the word got started as a participle and through frequent use achieved an independent status.)

As an adjective or participle, it would appear *languissante* needs a substantive to modify (or otherwise hang on to).

The only model I can think of, in which that happens, is this:

> She, only too happy to be asked, said yes.

That is to say, *languissante* is modifying (hooking into the rest of the clause through) *elle*.

Comment: Adjectif, oui. *Elle était languissante quand elle se relevait.* Je ne me rappelle pas du contexte de l’œuvre pour savoir de quel sens de [languissant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/languissant) il s'agit.

Comment: That seems clearly an example of a ["quasi-predicative adjective"](http://gabrielwyler.com/page127.html), which is a kind of adverbial expression.

Comment: @mlj Thanks! That looks exactly right. I guess these quasi-predicatives have a different range in different languages. For example, 'il s'est marié jeune' seems to work in both languages. 'She rose languid' would not work in English while 'she rose cold and hungry' might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour comprendre la phrase :

> ... ; elle  [s’allongeait aussitôt sur un sofa ou dans un hamac, demeurait étendue jusqu’au soir et] (ne) se relevait (que) languissante.

L'adjectif *languissante*, se découvre en enlevant :

- Entre `[]` une partie de la phrase à la fin de laquelle, *elle* n'est pas répété mais sous-entendu, car on parle toujours de la même personne,
- Entre `()` une forme négative.

*Languissante* est donc un adjectif se rapportant à *elle*.

Comment: Je reste toujours dans l'attente de la justification (recommandée par la charte du site) du vote négatif :)